# Creating custom nuget package to share common layout across projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, nuget, nuget-package

I've multiple ASP.NET MVC projects in multiple solutions. All of them needed to have same layout i.e. header, footer and navigation. I thought about using the **RazorGenerator** tool to create a separate MVC project and compile the reusable views into an assembly. But, along with the partial views, I also needed to embed the resources like images, css and (may be) javascripts as well. So I'm not sure whether RazorGenerator will help in this case (?)

Creating a custom nuget package is a good option in this case?

Is there any reference materiel available to create a custom nuget package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom nuget package does sounds like a good solution to me.

I used Scott Hanselman's tutorial for all my nuget packages, well worth a read:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/creatinganugetpackagein7easystepsplususingnugettointegrateaspnetmvc3intoexistingwebformsapplications.aspx